# Android app crashes, does not even launch. Null pointer exception?

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

My application crashes and says "CurrencyConverter keeps crashing". I honestly can't see where I have an error.

```
package com.example.currencycalculator

import android.app.Activity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import android.widget.Spinner

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var currencyPicker: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
        var userInput : EditText = findViewById(R.id.userInput)
        var toConvert : Currencies = Currencies(userInput)
        var convertedText : TextView = findViewById(R.id.endText)
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.currencyArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            currencyPicker.adapter = adapter
        }
        currencyPicker.onItemSelectedListener = SpinnerActivity()
        userInput.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                currencyPicker.setSelection(0)
            }

        })
        }

        inner class SpinnerActivity : Activity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            val userInput : EditText = findViewById(R.id.userInput)
            var toConvert : Currencies = Currencies(userInput)
            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                if (p2 == 0)
                {
                    toConvert.getPesos(userInput)
                }
                if (p2 == 1)
                {
                    toConvert.getCan(userInput)
                }
                if (p2 == 2)
                {
                    toConvert.getPesos(userInput)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

activity_main.xml
<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/layone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prompt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please choose the country to convert to:"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.414" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/prompt"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.093" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/prompt"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/endText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
        tools:text="Conversion:" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Currencies.kt

package com.example.currencycalculator

import android.widget.EditText

class Currencies(userInput: EditText) {
    fun getPesos(totalAmt:EditText): Double {
        var total: Double = totalAmt.text.toString().toDouble()
        //if (!totalAmt.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            val converted : Double = total * 20.765275
            return converted
        //}
        //else
           // return null!!.toDouble()
    }
    fun getCan(totalAmt:EditText) : Double {
        var total: Double = totalAmt.text.toString().toDouble()
        //if (!totalAmt.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            val converted : Double = total * 1.257629
            return converted
        //}
        //else
            //return null!!.toDouble()
    }
    fun getEuros(totalAmt:EditText) : Double {
        var total: Double = totalAmt.text.toString().toDouble()
        //if (!totalAmt.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            val converted : Double = total * 0.836502
            return converted
        //}
        //else
            //eturn null!!.toDouble()
    }
}
```

This is the Logcat:

```
03/11 13:40:34: Launching 'app' on No Devices.
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.currencycalculator/com.example.currencycalculator.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 3515 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:252): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=6766 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c139,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/rencycalculato: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/rencycalculato: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.currencycalculator, PID: 3515
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.currencycalculator/com.example.currencycalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:3209)
        at com.example.currencycalculator.MainActivity$SpinnerActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:43)
        at com.example.currencycalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:27)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

This is for a currency converter app, where I am using a Spinner to select the currency the user wants to convert to. The currencies class just holds the functions to calculate each currency.

In MainActivity, I am trying to use a TextWatcher to update the converted value, and represent it through a TextView (therefore no buttons are used). The EditText takes in the user input and this value is used by the Currencies class.

Comment: `inner class SpinnerActivity : Activity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` - why? Can't you make `currencyPicker.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {...}`?

Comment: Can you post the getPesos() method? Are you controlling there that there isn't a null value passed?

Comment: I made the suggested changes but I'm still getting the same exact error. As for the getPesos() method and others, there are no null values being passed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your inner class is a subclass of Activity for no good reason. When you call `findViewById` from inside this class, it is calling the `findViewById` of the inner class, and not of the MainActivity.

Since you are not using the inner class as a proper Activity, it does not have any views set up, so `findViewById` will fail.

Change your inner class into an anonymous object (and get rid of its redundant properties), just like you used for your text watcher.

```
    currencyPicker.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
            if (position == 0)
            {
                toConvert.getPesos(userInput)
            }
            if (position == 1)
            {
                toConvert.getCan(userInput)
            }
            if (position == 2)
            {
                toConvert.getPesos(userInput)
            }
        }
    }
```

I also suggest using a `when` statement for easier readability:

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
    when(position) {
        0, 2 -> toConvert.getPesos(userInput)
        1 -> toConvert.getCan(userInput)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I made the changes but I'm still getting the same error.